# Git on Arch linux on raspberry pi 3 crashes on clone

Tags: git

I really don't know why, but `git clone` is crashing my rpi3 and rebooting it, a few other programs do it but probably for different reasons.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't enough information here to do anything with. You'll need to do some more investigating - find some logs, check for weird memory use or a lack of storage, track down some specific error messages, etc., etc., etc. There are too many possibilities for us to negotiate here.

Comment: Reboots at high CPU load usually mean bad power supply.

Comment: oh, is that why i have a lightning bolt?

Comment: @Alex-c: yes that is exactly why you have the lightning bolt.

Comment: yea i changed it yesterday, no more lightning bolt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a better power supply

lightning bolt = bad

none = good